# Can virtualbox run on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualbox

I see that the host OS of VirtualBox can be Windows Werver 2008, but it doesn't explicitly say 2008 R2. Can it equally run on Windows Server R2?

Also can the guest OS be Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @womble I find it best practice not to work haphazardly with OS and virtual environment installs.

Comment: wtf glad to see somebody was able to make sense of this nonsense post.

Comment: @tonyroth Please tell me what doesn't make sense.  I thought my question quite clear.  I'll clarify if need be.  But it seems like ftiaronsem understood it perfectly.

Comment: nice to see that the post was edited makes more sense now.  But why run virtual box when you already have hyper-v?

Comment: hyper-v is free, but I kinda see what your doing here so ok I guess.

Comment: no preference unless you really want to scale up then go for hyper-v or esxi otherwise you're good to go.

Comment: I have to admit this sounds like a terrible idea. If you already own a license for Server R2, you can install the Hyper-V role. Hyper-V will give you a much better virtualization environment than VirtualBox.

Comment: don't think he's trying to use it like we'd use a traditional hypervisor he just wants to run a desktop thats virtual which VB give better options as in I think it supports usb etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtualbox will certainly run on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have never found a Windows or Linux host on which VirtualBox did not run. The guest OS can also be Windows Server 2008 R2. I have one running right next to me.